# ARM Trustzone, Open Virtualization SDK Boot stuck

Tags: arm, boot, trustzone

I am currently working on something related to ARM Trustzone so I found this Open Virtualization (http://openvirtualization.org/)
I followed the documentation over the [Sierra TEE build and boot guide](http://www.openvirtualization.org/SierraTEE_build_and_boot_guide.pdf) to build and it compiles without issues.

However when I am trying to boot the system, it seems it loops in the "normal world" forever and the log shows the following:

> Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to localhost. Escape charater is '^['.
>
> SW: Entering Secure Main
>
> SW: UART driver initialized successfully the mount file system is 32
>   and the value is 0 file system successfully mounted in FAT32 nsk
>   load:load addr = 80000000, startaddr = 90d00000, size = 3aedcc Done
>   tzhyp_guest_context_init:SW: dispatch task id 0x111

It seems it loops in the normal world forever and the boot process is stuck at this point.

If anyone happen to work on this before please help.